# custom data type has blank attributes when extending python with c++ using the boost_python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost-python

It is my first time to write a python wrapper for a opencv function.

the purpose of my project: writing a python wrapper for a c++ function with the help of boost python.

complication of the project: the return type is not standard.

a = mymodule.myfunction(args)

the data type of a is defined as the following

struct pyopencv_DMatch_t
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    cv::DMatch v;
};

problem that I need to address: after compilation, and importing the mymodule.so in python, I found the returned object in type pyopencv_DMatch_t has blank attribute, which means:

the output of dir(a) is []

but when I debug the code, and set a break point before first time using the variable a, and then print dir(a) again, I get the output differently:

['DMatch',
 '**class**',
 '**delattr**',
 '**doc**',
 '**format**',
 '**getattribute**',
 '**hash**',
 '**init**',
 '**new**',
 '**reduce**',
 '**reduce_ex**',
 '**repr**',
 '**setattr**',
 '**sizeof**',
 '**str**',
 '**subclasshook**',
 'distance',
 'imgIdx',
 'queryIdx',
 'trainIdx']

In other works, after importing the mymodule in python code, if I run the code directly, I get an error message says the object a has no attribute 'attribute_1', but if I set a break point before the first using of variable a,after the pause because of the break point, even I do nothing, the code can run correctly.

I have been stuck by this problem for days, and sincerely appreciate your help or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.